# How to import a 1x1 degree text file into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, import, text

I have a text file with 360 columns and 180 lines, each number indicating a value for a one-degree cell.

```
1.32    1.43    1.67    1.61    1.57    1.39    1.22    ...
1.19    1.28    1.22    1.07    0.94    0.76    0.69    ...
0.83    0.83    0.77    0.67    0.58    0.55    0.62    ...
...
```

I haven't found any indication on how such a file can be imported into QGIS. 
How can I do this?

Comment: The easiest might be to add an [ASCII raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/esri-ascii-raster-format.htm) header with "NCOLS 360 NROWS 180 XLLCORNER -180 YLLCORNER -90 CELLSIZE 1"

Comment: @Vince: Ah, great, that helped me to find my way through. Replacing the NaN with -9999 then in the next step, I could drag & drop it into QGIS. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nearly have a raster in [ASCII raster format](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/esri-ascii-raster-format.htm), all you need is to prepend the header lines:

```
NCOLS 360 
NROWS 180 
XLLCORNER -180 
YLLCORNER -90 
CELLSIZE 1
```

If there are NODATA values in the file which are not "-9999", you can either
replace them with "-9999", or use the `NODATA_VALUE` header keyword to specify
that value instead, for example:

```
NODATA_VALUE -98765
```

Most GIS packages will process the resulting file.